# How can I fetch names for devices whose bluetooth is on in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I want to fetch all on bluetooth devices. I am using SwiftyBluetooth.

```
import SwiftyBluetooth

SwiftyBluetooth.scanForPeripherals(withServiceUUIDs: nil, timeoutAfter: 15) { scanResult in
    switch scanResult {
    case .scanStarted:
        // The scan started meaning CBCentralManager scanForPeripherals(...) was called
        print("scan Started")
    case .scanResult(let peripheral, let advertisementData, let RSSI):

        // A peripheral was found, your closure may be called multiple time with a .ScanResult enum case.
        // You can save that peripheral for future use, or call some of its functions directly in this closure.
        print("::::\(peripheral)")
        self.peripheralArray.append(peripheral)
        print("\(advertisementData)")
        print("RSSI\(RSSI)")
    case .scanStopped(let error):
        print("error\(error)")
        // The scan stopped, an error is passed if the scan stopped unexpectedly
    }
}
```

This code give me names of Mi bands and tvs but not of iPhones or android phones anyway to get phones also.

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation says, i assume it is the name...?

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SwiftyBluetooth/1.0.0/Classes/Peripheral.html#/s:vC15SwiftyBluetooth10Peripheral4nameGSqSS_

Comment: yea I want to fetch name but its not showing iPhones in list but it shows Samsung tv and bands

Comment: ok, then i would guess that Apple does not give us the names... ;)